# What should be the path stored in XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, prism

I have created a WPF project using PRISM. Here is the structure of my application:

```
MySolution
|-Business //Folder
  |-StaticData //This Project Contains XML file which contains data about menu and navigation.
  |-Data
|-Modules //Folder
  |-MenuModule
  |-MembersModule
    |-View1
    |-View2
    |-View3
|-MainProject //Startup Project
|-Infrastructure
```

I want to use View-Based Navigation in this application. My menu is generated dynamically from XML File. So, I also want to store the Navigation URI in this XML file.

I have used `xcopy` command to copy the dll of ModuleMembers automatically in the current Directory.

I have tried:

```
Modules/ModuleMembers/View1xaml   and
pack://application:,,,/Modules/ModuleMembers/View1xaml
```

But I always get System.Object instead of View in the output.

You might say that this the problem of Registering modules. But that's not a problem. Here is the code for registration :

```
_container.RegisterType<object, View1>(typeof(View1).FullName);
```

So, I think that The path of the View stored in XML file needs to be changed.

Thanks.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it. It was very simple.

So, My xml should contain:

```
ModuleMembers.View1
```